# data duplicated from stored procedure using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using entity framework in VS2010 .NET 3.5 to expose a stored procuedure. The results in VS are incorrect, but the result manually executing the stored procedure look good. For example:

Here is the sp that returns only the distinct names based on a search string using LIKE:

```
SELECT Name,GETDATE() AS Date FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Customers WHERE Name LIKE 'br') dt_result
```

When executed from Query Analyzer in SQL Mgt Studio results look correct:

```
Name       Date
Brian      2011-12-01 10:59:40.093
Brady      2011-12-01 10:59:40.093
Bryan      2011-12-01 10:59:40.093
```

My code to expose the results of the stored procuedure in VS looks like this:

```
var results = (from i in dbentities.SearchName('br')
                       select i).ToList();
```

But results contains this:

```
Name       Date
Brian      2011-12-01 10:59:40.093
Brian      2011-12-01 10:59:40.093
Brian      2011-12-01 10:59:40.093
```

The number of entities is correct but the property contain the same value. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your keys on the Entity are probably not unique. This little bug has caught me multiple times when returning results from stored procedures into entities.

To fix it simply go into your Entity model remove the existing keys on the entity and ensure the new key you pick is unique.

Hopefully this helps.